# CultureInfo differs between .NET Core and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, locale, globalization, cultureinfo

There seems to be some difference for CultureInfo between **.NET Core** and **.NET Framework**.
Is there any reason to this?

Example:

```
var italian = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it").TextInfo.CultureName;
```

On **.NET Core** resolves to:

```
it
```

While it previously resolved to on **.NET Framework** to:

```
it-IT
```

This breaks some unit tests.
Running this in two clean Console projects yield different results.
Tried adding System.Globalization from Nuget without no difference in results.

Is there some configuration needed for this to be the same or have they broken CultureInfo altogheter?

Comment: The [documentation for CultureInfo]
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8#cultureinfo-and-cultural-data) mentions the cultures available could vary by operating system. Maybe that's what is happening?

Comment: I would always try to work with subcultures. It is amazing how many differences are in big cultures with several subcultures. To globalize your code you should move into a subculture level code to avoid future problems

Answer (score 2):

I confirm this behaviour, but Core is more conclusive.

You ask for culture "it", you get culture "it".

.NET Framework is adding more details and specifies a default subculture to it-IT.

If you ask for

```
var italian = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT").TextInfo.CultureName;
```

directly.

You will get the same result in both worlds.

To change that string should be a minor problem for your tests.

Comment: Except that being explicit with the info are also not working: var culture = new CultureInfo(new RegionInfo("sv-SE").Name); // Northern Sami in Core and Swedish in NET.